# powershell: invoke-sqlcmd catching errors when using -InputFile instead of -Query

Tags: sql, powershell, error-handling

I have an powershell script which is executing sql scripts from a given folder. This is working, but in case of error I don't see the reason of the error. In some cases the error is displayed, when the powershell itself throws the error. But when it's a more simple failure such as a primary key conflict, no error is shown.

I've tried it the following way, but this does not work when using the "-InputFile" parameter. Replacing this by the "-Query" Parameter and the error will be shown.

```
try 
{
    sqlps Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$dbInstance" -Database "$dbName" -InputFile "$updateScriptsFolder\$updateSql" -username $username -password $password -ErrorAction 'Stop' -Verbose -OutputSqlErrors 1
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Error while executing $updateScriptsFolder\$updateSql" -foregroundcolor red
    Write-Host $error -foregroundcolor red
}
```

The only solution for now is to add the error handling to every sql script. But it's very likely that developers forget to add the errorhandling to their script.  I want a more general error handling. Can anybody help?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Is there a reason you don't read the file into a string variable and use that variable as the value for the -query parameter?

Comment: Cool... I'll add my comment as an answer to stop this appearing unanswered (although I'm not sure if that's the correct S.O. etiquette).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments above, read the file into a string variable and use that variable as the value for the -query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error when using `-InputFile` instead of `-Query`, but that wasn't the actual problem. The problem was that I had been improperly attempting to set a value (`false`) for `-TrustServerCertificate`. Once I removed that value, `-InputFile` started working just fine.