# Powershell: Log the results of a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, powershell

Stemming from this post: [Powershell: Specify file path as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955774/powershell-specify-file-path-as-variable)

I am using Invoke-Sqlcmd in a PowerShell script to execute the following sql query:

```
update [$Db_name].[dbo].[$BatchTable]
set [$Db_name].[dbo].[$BatchTable].Wave = 'Wave1'
from [$Db_name].[dbo].[$BatchTable]
inner join OPENROWSET(BULK '$FILEPATH',    
FORMATFILE= 'C:\import.xml') AS a
on ([$Db_name].[dbo].[$BatchTable].Name= a.Name) and  
([$Db_name].[dbo].[$BatchTable].Domain = a.Domain)
```

I am logging a few messages but I am wondering how I can log any errors when the update query is run as well as when a match is found (optimally display a count successful and unsuccessful matches)

Comment: Are you looking to log SQL errors or PowerShell errors?

Comment: I am looking to log SQL error

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx) mentions that you could use the `-OutputSqlErrors` command line parameter with Invoke-Sqlcmd to display errors encountered while executing the SQL command.

**EDIT:** This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749616/powershell-invoke-sqlcmd-catching-errors-when-using-inputfile-instead-of-quer) might also be helpful to you